# IE11 Table Display Issue - Line in table head

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-11

I've created a table, which renders correctly in all browsers I've tested, including IE 8,9,10 etc.
However, in IE11 the last header column seems to have a border with the column before, creating a white line.

JSFiddle recreating the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/xx4Z4/32/

HTML:

```
  <table class ="table_compare">
        <colgroup>
            <col class="tablefeature" />
            <col span="3"/>
        </colgroup>

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="first"><h2>Heading 1</h2></th>
                <th><h2>Heading 2</h2></th>
                <th><h2>Heaading 3</h2></th>
                <th class="last"><h2>Heading 4 - IE Issue</h2></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="feat">Feature 1</td>
                <td>Text 1</td>
                <td>Text 2</td>
                <td>Text 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="light_grey_bg">
                <td class="feat">Feature 2</td>
                <td>Text 1</td>
                <td>Text 2</td>
                <td>Text 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="feat">Feature 3</td>
                <td>Text 1</td>
                <td>Text 2</td>
                <td>Text 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="order_row">
                <td class="feat">Last row</td>
                <td>First</td>
                <td>Second</td>
                <td>Third</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
  </table>
```

CSS:

```
.table_compare{
    border-spacing: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-collapse: separate;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 600px;
    margin-top: 22px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table_compare tbody{
    border-top-width: thin;
    border-right-width: thin;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-color: #c2c2c2;
}

.table_compare thead th{
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0;
    background: #555;
    background-position: 0 bottom;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}

.table_compare th.first{
    border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
}

.table_compare th.last{
    border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
}


.table_compare h2{
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
}

.table_compare tbody, .table_compare thead, .table_compare tr,     .table_compare th, .table_compare td{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.table_compare td{
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: thin;
    border-spacing: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:28px;
    border-right-color: #c2c2c2;
}

.table_compare td.feat, .table_compare th.first{
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 257px;
}

.table_compare td.feat{
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: thin;
    border-left-color: #c2c2c2;
}

.light_grey_bg, .order_row{
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
}

.light_grey_bg, .order_row{
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
}

.order_row td{
    height: 37px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
    border-bottom-color: #c2c2c2;
}
```

Does anybody know the cause of the problem?

It must be the CSS somewhere, but why IE11 is doing this I don't know.

Image: [image]

Comment: Have you tried adding `border: none` to the `<th>` elements?

Comment: It seems to be connected to the `border-radius` – once that is removed, the effect is gone as well.

Comment: The code in the jsfiddle is rather different from the code posted. A question should include code that is sufficient for actually reproducing the issue; this one isn’t.

Comment: I can post it all but it's rather large, should I include all the code in the question? This was my first post. Thought it'd be easier to just provide a link

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, but I require the border-radius. Seems bizarre.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: The issue is reproducible just fine for me with the fiddle given.

Comment: There seem to be certain issues with IE 11 and `border-radius` – a quick search reveals that there’s other questions about similar issues already; maybe you can find a solution or workaround in one of those.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, will keep trying. Interestingly the white line changes/disappears if the Heading 3 column width changes. - e.g. by changing the heading text

Comment: @Protagonist: [This](http://blog.jonschneider.com/2014/03/fix-css-border-radius-not-working-in.html) might be helpful.

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi No cigar I'm afraid, thanks though.

Comment: @bowheart border: none has no impact. It's not actually a border, more a graphical glitch it seems, as the line appears to be around 0.5px wide. It seems IE will never cease to be a pain.

Comment: :D I agree with you on IE part!

Comment: I can confirm it's the white background coming through. On the jsfiddle, if you move the centre window divider around to widen or shorten the preview window you can see it appear or disappear. Applying a background colour to the thead or thead tr alleviates the line a little, as then takes some colour from that background. @CBroe, unfortuntely haven't found an answer from other searches, they seem to be other IE issues. This really seems like a rendering bug to me.

Comment: The code in the question, even after edits, does *not* reproduce the issue (and it lacks the crucial `table` tag). At SO, questions should be self-contained if possible, and here it surely is possible. But if you have not taken the trouble of reducing the problem to a minimized case and you only provide a jsfiddle link, it is better to include no code than to include fragments of code that do not reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I put all the jsfiddle code in, so it did reproduce the error. The opening table tag did exist, but for some reason didn't show. I did reproduce the problem to a minimised case. The jsfiddle code, and code in the question is not that of the web page, which included background images etc. It was a large table with a lot of content. I thought it prudent to have as much of the original css as possible. Again, this is my first post, and trying to do this as meant to, but don't understand what the issue is. If it bothers you that much then you can just ignore it?

Comment: The issue is that questions and answers should be useful to future visitors. For this reason, and other reasons, questions should be self-contained and well-formulated. After adding the `table` tag with a crucial attribute, the code now reproduces the issue. It’s still not optimal for a problem description, since it contain many apparently irrelevant features, like versions of CSS properities prefixed with other browser vendors’ prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an IE 11 bug, triggered by some special combination of settings, so that various modifications make it go away. One possibility is to remove the following code, which does not seem to have any effect except this bug:

```
.table_compare td.feat{
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: thin;
    border-left-color: #c2c2c2;
}
```

Another way, a simplistic one, is to explicitly set border on the last header cell, with the same color as the background, by adding this:

```
.table_compare th.last { border-left: solid #555 1px }
```

Comment: Thanks, however I require td.feat to define the left border. Table borders are separate, and the table itself doesn't have a border - left border is defined by the first td cell. I did this originally as different browsers calculate border collapse differently, and it caused misalignment. border-left works inconsistently in jsfiddle, tried that myself. However it's no good as the actual table has a background image for the header. Original thought was to try border-left: 1px solid transparent; However as using an image, that causes 1px of white to come through.

Comment: In fact, in testing neither fixes the issue. Simply widening the window will make the lines appear again. Borders or padding seem to work when the window is a certain width, but not at others. Removing td.feat also introduces another visual bug, of blurring on the bottom of first and last th cells. As per this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348947/ie11-blurry-right-hand-edge-of-div-with-border-radius

Comment: Unfortunately still can't find a fix for this. Only other mention of it I found was a bug reported to Microsoft which they closed as unreproducible, but it clearly is reproducible.

Comment: Here is similar bug report: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/794878/ and my new submission: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/972987